# The following classes could not be found! “Android-cardview”

Tags: java, android, kotlin

What causes the following error in the `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` in Android Studio?

Render errors I get this error:

[image]

I have already Added `CardView` dependency in the `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

I also made a clean project and did a rebuild, but with no result.
[this is layout.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgIo4.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried reimporting the dependencies and checking all of them are actually found?

Comment: Have you tried invalidated cache and restarted android studio.

Comment: yes i have  invalidated cache and restarted android studio with no result also !!

Comment: and how to reimporting the dependencies and checking all of them are actually found?